# Какие есть способы корректно сослаться на (потенциально) перемещаемый (в памяти) объект?

Tags: c++, smart-pointer, heap, move, new

Вопрос связан с move-семантикой C++ с одной стороны и с реаллокацией - с другой.

Чтобы была яснее суть, буду подразумевать, что на объект Dependency может ссылаться некоторое количество объектов Target. Т.е. Dependency это (потенциально) нечто более-менее "unique", "shared" и нечто более-менее "const" - большую часть времени. Например, в качестве Dependency можно подразумевать какой-либо буфер в OpenGL или OpenAL, который может загружаться из файла и выгружаться из оперативной памяти, а потому - присутствовать или отсутствовать в ней. Т.е. общая идея, это `*_map<Key, something<Dependency>>`, в которую, по мере необходимости, добавляются или удаляются Dependency и из которой берут (изначально) их объекты Target. (Отношения между Dependency и Target можно рассматривать как Target - наблюдатель (observer) Dependency, Target - легковесный (flyweight) Dependency, Target - заместитель (proxy) Dependency. **А суть моего вопроса упирается в способ поддержания актуальности указателей между ними.** Пример сценария использования: создаётся какой-то объект - скажем - персонаж видеоигры, содержащий разные Target-ы для графики и аудио, принимает в конструкторе кэш, в основе которого - словарь, его Target-ы ищут в кэше-словаре нужные им Dependency, а если не находят - загружают и добавляют их в кэш-словарь, а когда объект персонаж уничтожается, его Target-ы тоже уничтожается, по мере необходимости, удаляя лишние Dependency из кэша-словаря.)

Это была общая идея, а дальше начинаются частности: **как и где будут создаваться и храниться объекты Dependency и как обеспечить корректность ссылок из Target на Dependency**.

Собственно, написав `something<Dependency>`, я имел в виду то, что в качестве значения в словаре могут быть как сами экземпляры Dependency, так и указатели на них. А главная составляющая выбора (связанная с семантикой перемещения и реаллокацией), это:

0. Какой словарь использовать (например, `std::map, std::unordered_map, boost::containers::flat_map`)?
1. Хранить в словаре сами объекты?
2. Или в словаре хранить указатели на объекты, находящиеся в другом контейнере?
3. Или в словаре хранить умные указатели, а сами объекты создавать в куче по отдельности?

В эти вопросы упирается ответ на заданный мной вопрос о корректном способе сослаться на потенциально перемещаемый в памяти объект (Dependency), например:

1. Если использовать, например, `flat_map`, то объекты Dependency будут перемещаться в памяти по мере добавления/удаления объектов в словарь из-за реаллокаций, следовательно, просто указателей из Target на Dependency не достаточно. Нужно или не использовать `flat_map`, или хранить в словаре только умные указатели (выделять место под Dependency в куче), или придётся как-то прикрутить к Dependency какой-то механизм обновления всех ссылающихся на Dependency указателей в объектах Target - сделать что-то вроде наблюдателя, где субъект - Dependency, наблюдатель - Target, а события - срабатывание конструктора перемещения/перемещающего присваивания или деструктора Dependency.
2. Если использовать `std::map` или `std::unordered_map`, то можно обойтись обычными указателями из Target на Dependency и обратно, добавив методы обработки для событий удаления Target или Dependency. Получается что-то вроде наблюдателя, где субъект - Dependency, уведомляет всех своих наблюдателей (Target) о срабатывании своего деструктора, а любой Target в деструкторе прекращает свою регистрацию на событие разрушения Dependency.

С одной стороны, желательно, чтобы при обращении (по очереди) к нескольким Target-ам (ссылающимся на соответствующие им Dependency), при обращении к Dependency, было как можно меньше прыжков по памяти: т.е., в идеале, они должны находиться в непрерывном участке памяти или (чуть хуже) в нескольких непрерывных блоках (по несколько Dependency на блок). Это аргумент в пользу `flat_map` и близких к её использованию решений. (Альтернатива - написание кастомного аллокатора, выделяющего память блоками.)

С другой стороны, нужна 100% гарантия, что любой указатель из Target на Dependency корректен: он обязательно должен быть или в нулевом состоянии, или указывать на какой-нибудь Dependency - в любой момент времени. Это аргумент против `flat_map` и близких к её использованию решений. Это вынуждает примиряться либо с как попало разбросанными в куче нодами (`std::map` или `std::unordered_map`), либо с использованием умных указателей и созданием Dependency в куче, либо с необходимостью городить "наблюдатель перемещения Dependency", хранящий в контейнере, указатели на Target (что мне показалось неудобным).

С третьей, чем меньше делается обращений к куче, тем лучше. Как с т.з. экономии памяти, так и с т.з. того, чтобы поменьше дёргать ОС и "ждать вечность", когда ОСь вернёт какой-нибудь кусочек памяти. Это аргумент против создания Dependency в куче с умными указателями: мало того, что аллоцируется место в контейнере, но ещё и make_умный_указатель ещё раз выделяет память в куче - это для создания одного и того же элемента (Dependency).

С четвёртой, всё осложняется тем, что Target и Dependency могут находиться в разных потоках исполнения (т.е. контейнер с Dependency - в одном потоке, а Target-ы могут находиться в любых других `thread`-ах). Это аргумент против, в первую очередь, самодельного "наблюдателя перемещения Dependency", состоящего из прикручивания контейнера указателей на Target в Dependency, методов взаимной регистрации и разрегистрации в Target и Dependency и обработки событий удаления или перемещения Dependency в памяти (прохода по всем зарегистрированным Target-ам): периодически, при изменении количества элементов, в случае с `flat_map`-подобными решениями, будет реаллокация, а значит - перемещение Dependency, а значит - рассылка уведомлений всем Target, а значит - синхронизация, притом, довольно мудрёная (это, не говоря, о том, что само по себе - без потоков - такое решение не из простых).

**Соответственно, какой вариант предпочтительнее (и почему)? - Как лучше реализовать словарь-кэш Dependency, чтобы и на (потенциально) перемещаемые Dependency можно было сослаться, и не убить производительность реаллокациями/синхронизацией/множественными прыжками по удалённым местам памяти/множественными выделениями памяти в куче? Или, быть может, я напрасно задаюсь такими вопросами, когда весь мир уже давно работает по методологии "раз-два и в продакшн"?**

Comment: Вместо длинного и мутного описания вам стоило бы привести конкретный пример кода. Из него даже не ясно, почему Dependency должно обязательно перемещаться куда-то.

Comment: user7860670 - вопрос более общего плана, чем любой конкретный пример кода. Он скорее про архитектуру и/или подбор средств, чем кодирование. (Х.з., может подобного плана вопросы не совсем по тематике Stackoverflow, ИМХО - это неоднозначно). Dependency **может** перемещаться - в зависимости от реализации. Вопрос про то, какой вариант (путь) реализации выбрать. И про то, как подобным задачам (по умолчанию), стоит подходить. Даже конкретные названия классов - Dependency и Target - даны, чтобы дать хоть какую-то конкретику. Вопрос связан с C++, т.к., например, в Java, был бы просто наблюдатель.

Comment: Ну строго говоря, никакие объекты в С++ перемещаться не могут. Если у вас сценарий, при котором вместо одного объекта начинает использоваться другой, то для нахождения новой версии можно использовать https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern

Comment: user7860670 извините, не очень понял, что значит "объекты в С++ перемещаться не могут". Скажем, `T::T(T&& src)` конструктор перемещения? - Насколько знаю - да. `T x(std::move(y))` - перемещает ресурсы из `y` в `x`. Закономерно, что раз есть move-consturctor/assignment, рассматривать такой вызов как event перемещения объекта в памяти и по нему перенаправлять указатели его наблюдателей (в примере выше - с y на x) со старого на новый объект: с т.з. C++ убивается старый и создаётся новый объект, а с т.з. логики тот же объект перемещается в памяти. Извращение ли это? - Про это в т.ч. и был вопрос.

Comment: "перемещения объекта в памяти" не бывает. Адрес объекта фиксируется перед началом его жизни и остается неизменным вплоть до окончания. Рассматривать такое, как event перемещения объекта в памяти не стоит. Сценарий с выделением функционала по отслеживания указателя на актуальный объект решает уже упомянутый паттерн локатор. Собственно если зависимость задана явно, то и объект уничтожать и создавать новый незачем, так как старый еще используется.

Comment: user7860670 из требования фиксированного адреса, следует, что создавать такой объект в реаллоцирующем контейнере (типа vector и flat_*) и хранить на него указатели нельзя - отвалятся при реаллокации: для фиксированного объекта придётся или не хранить такие в непрерывном участке памяти, или заполнять условный vector (или flat_) один раз (т.к. добавление/удаление потребует - рано или поздно - реаллоцировать непрерывный участок памяти и убьёт все указатели). Вероятно, я "пытаюсь усидеть" даже не на "двух", а на "нескольких стульях" - стремление располагать объекты поближе в памяти - один из них.

Answer (score 1):

Решение, простое как табуретка:

- Target-ы хранят у себя `shared_ptr`ы на свои dependency.
- Кеш для dependency хранит в себе `weak_ptr`ы на них. В `std::map` или любой другой мапе. Периодически из нее можно вычищать протухшие указатели.

Тогда нет необходимости перемещать в памяти dependency.

А про оптимизацию будете думать, когда у вас код начнет тормозить. Если все написать нормально, то должно быть возможно легко подменить начинку, не переписывая никакие target-ы и dependency.

---

Еще, будь это мой код, я бы поменял названия target и dependency...

Answer (score 0):

*Нулевое. Очень многа букав, хочется влепить сюда гифку с Кариной.*

Первое. Преждевременная оптимизация - корень зла. Современные машины и компиляторы достаточно сообразительны для того, чтобы не тратить человеческие ресурсы на решение абстрактной задачи. Причем на деле может оказаться, что реальная проблема с быстродействием находится вообще в другом месте.

Так что первое приближение в виде *фигак-в продакшн* позволяет проверить принципиальную работоспособность идеи (а это 80% рыночной стоимости нового кода как правило), а потом прогнать профайлер и найти проблемы.

Ближайшим решением, реализующим хотелку, является библиотека facebook folly, там есть контейнер, который при помещении объекта в него дает на него перманентрый атомарный токен, по которому к объекту можно быстро добраться.

Под капотом у нее lock-free алгоритмы, поэтому работает она гораздо шустрее `std::map` с мьютексом, например. Исходники открыты, так что можете [восхититься](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/AtomicHashMap.md)

**В общем случае, на ваш вопрос однозначно ответить нельзя, потому что мелкие изменения в постановке задачи могут все предложенное решение сделать неработоспособным.**